# Stack Exchange only recognizes me when I try to recover my account

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts

I have a Stack Exchange account connected with my Google account, but the platform won't recognize me (log ins/sign ins are useless; it acts as if I had to create a new account) until I open https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery. When I open that page, it instantly 'recognizes' me and acts as if I was already logged in.

Is that a bug or there is an explanation for that?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this correctly - home page thinks you're not logged in, but /users/account-recovery thinks you are (and you see your avatar in the top bar, etc)?

Comment: Which browser (IE/Chrome/FF + version) are you using and on which OS are you? Is this your own device with your own software or are you on a corporate  network/device?

Comment: Do you get any failed messages: [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help)

Comment: @AnnaLear thats it. For rene - Its Firefox and I don't get any error on that page.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to try it on another browser. This could be a cache problem. If you clear your cache and cookies, you might be able to resolve this.

Comment: +1 for clearing cache/cookies.

Comment: @Anna is this a secret dev power, a hidden upvote? ;-)

Comment: Now I'm unable to reproduce it now because the "log in with google" is apparently working here now.